# Prove/disprove $(\int_0^{2 \pi} \!\!\cos f(x) \, d x)^2+(\int_0^{2 \pi}\!\!\! \sqrt{(f'(x))^2+\sin ^2 f(x)} \, dx)^2\ge 4\pi^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

> Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function on $[0,2\pi]$ s.t. $0\leq f(x)\leq 2\pi$ and $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. Prove or disprove that
> $$
> \left(\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos f(x) \,d x\right)^2+\left(\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{(f'(x))^2+\sin^2 f(x)} \, d x\right)^2 \geq(2 \pi)^2
> $$

---

It seems that when $f$ is an arbitrary constant, the left side equals $(2\pi)^2$ and seems to be the minimum. But how can I show that there's no other $f$ that makes the left side equal (or be less than) $(2\pi)^2$?

---

A geometric interpretation of the inequality has been found: Consider a closed curve on a sphere: $C=\{(\cos x\cdot\sin f(x),\,\sin x\cdot\sin f(x),\,\cos f(x))\mid x\in[0,2\pi)\}$, we have its perimeter $\displaystyle L=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(f'(x))^2+\sin^2 f(x)}\,dx$ and its area $\displaystyle S=2\pi-\int_0^{2\pi}\cos f(x)\,dx$. From [spherical isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#On_a_sphere) $L^2\ge S(4\pi-S)$, we have $(2\pi-S)^2+L^2\ge(2\pi)^2$, and the equality holds iff $C$ is any circle on the sphere. In this way we get the original inequality in the sense of geometry.

Now the question is, how to prove the inequality with **only pure analysis methods**?

Comment: Its a nice inequality where did you get this?

Comment: Jensen's inequality goes the other way unfortunately, and gives an *upper* bound of $(2\pi)^2 + \int (f'(x))^2 dx$

Comment: I suspect that $\int_0^{2\pi} f'(x)=0$ is to be used somehow

Comment: I wonder if this can somehow be used here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/117296/42969.

Comment: It is found by accident when considering an equal-perimeter inequality on a sphere. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: @FFjet: If there is a geometric interpretation of that inequality then I suggest that you add it to your question. That may help to understand the problem better and possibly to find an answer.

Comment: I guess that if in the first integral we have $|\cos f(x)|$ instead of $\cos f(x)$ (and the function $\sqrt{(f'(x))^{2}+\sin ^{2} f(x)}$ is integrable on $[0,2\pi]$) then the required inequality would follow from an integral [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: It probably does not make any difference, but apparently $f(x)$ is the azimuthal angle corresponding to the polar angle $x$, so it might make sense to restrict $f(x)$ to the interval $[0, \pi]$.

Comment: Notice that by the reverse Minkowski inequality: $(2 \pi)^{2}\geq(\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \cos f(x) d x)^{2}+(\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sin f(x) d x)^{2}$

Comment: By the sandwich rule you just need to prove that: $$(\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sqrt{(f'(x))^{2}+\sin ^{2} f(x)} d x)^{2} \geq (\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sin f(x) d x)^{2}$$

Comment: Now since $f'(x) \in R$ then $(f'(x))^2>0$, thus $(f'(x))^2+\sin^2 f(x) \ge \sin^2 f(x)$ verifying the above inequality.

Comment: Isoperimetric inequality directly follows from Wirtinger's inequality which is basic Fourier Analysis. So I suppose you don't consider the latter pure analysis?

Comment: Can we find an example of non-constant feasible $f(x)$ such that $C = \{(\cos x\, \sin f(x),\, \sin x \, \sin f(x), \,\cos f(x)) : x \in [0, 2\pi]\}$ is a circle?

Answer (score 1):

<This is not an answer!! This is just some of my thoughts, and also I am not good at English. If there are any things to fix, please be my guest.>

> Prediction: For two functions $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, $$(\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} A(x) dx)^2+(\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} B(x) dx)^2 \geq (\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \sqrt{A(x)^2+B(x)^2} dx)^2 $$
> holds.

If this is true(which I am not able to prove...), the problem can be solved easily.

Let $A(x)=\cos f(x)$ and $B(x)=\sqrt{{f'(x)}^2+\sin^2 f(x)}$, and $\alpha=0, \beta=2\pi$. 
Then, by the Prediction, $$(\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos f(x) dx)^2+(\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{(f'(x))^2+\sin^2 f(x)} dx)^2\geq (\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{(f'(x))^2+1}  dx)^2 $$
We know that the right hand side is the form of the length of a curve $f(x)$.
As $y=f(x)$ satisfies $f(0)=f(2\pi)$, the shortest length of the curve $y=f(x)$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ would be just a simple line connecting $(0, f(0))$ and $(2\pi, f(2\pi)=f(0))$, so the length will be just the x-coordinate difference, which is $2\pi$. Therefore, the RHS will have the minimum of $(2\pi)^2=4\pi^2$, and the problem is solved. 
However, I couldn't think of a sharp way to prove this Prediction, or even it is true at all. I managed to think of the integrals as sequences, and tried solving this.
$$(\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k)^2+(\sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k)^2 \geq (\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{(a_k)^2+(b_k)^2})^2$$
I think this equation can be solved by mathematical induction, but I am not sure.

Comment: prediction is false, just take $A=B=\sin(x -\frac{\alpha+\beta}2)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Oh thanks! I wonder if the opposite direction is right...is it?

Comment: yes, it’s just triangle inequality for integrals of $\mathbb R^2$ valued functions ie $|\int \binom AB dx| \le \int|\binom AB | dx$

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer (for now), just observations**:

We can at least prove that the left-side must be strictly positive. Moreover, this can be done without assuming that $0\leq f(x)\leq 2\pi$ and $f(2\pi)=f(0)$.

**Proof**: since any sum of squares is at least $0$, the following inequality holds for all differentiable functions $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ for which the integrals exist:

$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos[f(x)]dx\right)^2+\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left[f'(x)\right]^2+\sin^2\left[f(x)\right]}\text{ }dx\right)^2\geq 0$$

Suppose, for the sake of finding a contradiction, that there is a differentiable $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ for which

$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos[f(x)]dx\right)^2+\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left[f'(x)\right]^2+\sin^2\left[f(x)\right]}\text{ }dx\right)^2= 0$$

Since $x^2+y^2=0$ if and only if $x=y=0$, it follows that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos[f(x)]dx=0\text{ and }\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left[f'(x)\right]^2+\sin^2\left[f(x)\right]}\text{ }dx=0$$

From [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142535/proof-verification-if-int-ab-sqrtfxgx-dx-0-f-and-g-are-both-n) together with the observations that $[f'(x)]^2\geq 0$, $\sin^2[f(x)]\geq 0$, and $(\sin\circ f)^2$ is continuous, we can infer that

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left[f'(x)\right]^2+\sin^2\left[f(x)\right]}\text{ }dx=0 &\implies \sin^2[f(x)]=0\text{ for every }x\in[0,2\pi]\\
&\implies \sin[f(x)]=0\text{ for every }x\in[0,2\pi]\\
&\implies \text{For every }x\in[0,2\pi]\text{, }f(x)=\pi n\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}

From the continuity of $f$, we deduce that $f=(\pi n)_{[0,2\pi]}$ for some integer $n$ (the notation $c_{[a,b]}$ denotes the constant function mapping $[a,b]$ to $c$). This implies that $\cos\circ f=\pm 1_{[0,2\pi]}$, and consequently

$$\color{red}{0}=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos[f(x)]dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\pm 1dx\color{red}{=\pm 2\pi}$$

a contradiction. Thus, for every differentiable $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R$,

$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos[f(x)]dx\right)^2+\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left[f'(x)\right]^2+\sin^2\left[f(x)\right]}\text{ }dx\right)^2>0$$

I'm still thinking about how to prove the lower bound of $(2\pi)^2$. Stay tuned :)

Answer (score 0):

Also not an answer, but my train of thoughts. We can take advantage of the fact that for a complex number $z$ and its conjugate $\bar{z}$, it holds that $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$.

Thus, if we associate $$z(x)=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\cos f(x)+i\sqrt{(f'(x))^{2}+\sin ^{2} f(x)}\right)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}e^{i\phi(x)}dx,$$

the LHS becomes $z(x)\overline{z(x)}$ and thus we want to show that $$\left|\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}e^{i\phi(x)}dx\right|^2 \geq (2\pi)^2$$

<strike>Now, somewhat fishy, but I believe since the function $f(x)$ is positive on the interval $(0, 2\pi)$, and also $\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$ is positive, the following equality should hold:
$$\color{gray}{\left|\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}e^{i\phi(x)}dx\right|=\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}e^{i\phi(x)}\right|dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx=L}$$</strike>

Then, by the same argument as in the answer by @Joshua Woo, this is a length of the curve $f(x)$, which must be greater than the length of interval ($0$, $2\pi$), i.e., $L=2\pi$ (due to the condition $f(0)=f(2\pi)$), therefore we get the required inequality.

But I will be happy to learn where my argument is incorrect.

EDIT: Thanks for pointing out the error. I will keep the post struck-through just for the transparency.

Comment: As your argument goes, we are free to choose f(x) and phi(x) however we like, but what if f(x) = 1 and phi(x) = x, so that your integral is the integral of e^ix from 0 to 2pi, which is 0, so the ideal inequality isn't so.

Comment: @Countingstuff $\phi(x)$ is not any function, it is the phase of the complex number, i.e., $\phi(x)=\arctan\frac{\sqrt{(f'(x))^2+\sin^2f(x)}}{\cos f(x)}$, so for $f(x)=1$, $\phi(x)=1$. Also, note that absolute value of $e^{i\phi(x)}$ is 1 regardless of $\phi(x)$.

Comment: $\left|\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}e^{i\phi(x)}dx\right|=\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}e^{i\phi(x)}\right|dx$ is wrong unless the argument $\phi(x)$ is constant. In general you only have $\le$ which does not help.

Comment: @MartinR, I believe that linear dependence with the magnitude would sufficient. But I guess I can't guarantee that neither.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am simplifying this too much, but if f(x) is not constant, then $$\sqrt{(f'(x))^2 + (\sin f(x))^2} > |\sin f(x)|$$ because $$f'(x) \neq 0$$ for some value(s) in the interval of integration. This leads to the following:
$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi} \cos f(x) \: dx \right)^2 + \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(f'(x))^2 + \sin^2 f(x)} \: dx \right)^2 $$
$$ \geq \left(\int_0^{2\pi} \cos f(x) \: dx \right)^2 + \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\sin^2 f(x))^2} \: dx \right)^2 = (2 \pi)^2$$

Comment: If the $\cos$ and the $\sin$ were the objects being squared, then the last equality would certainly be true. However, it’s not the functions that are being squared, but their integrals, so I don’t understand how you deduced that their sum is $(2\pi)^2$. Could you be kind enough to explain your reasoning?