# Proof verification: if $\int_a^b \sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\,dx=0$, $f$ and $g$ are both non-negative, and $f$ is continuous, then $f\equiv 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

As a math-for-fun exercise, and also to supply my problem-solving toolbox with new inequalities, I challenged myself to attack this problem:

> If $\int_a^b \sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\,dx=0$, $f$ and $g$ are both non-negative on $[a,b]$, and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, is $f$ identically $0$ on $[a,b]$?

I think I've produced an argument that proves the answer is yes. Here it is:

Suppose, for the sake of finding a contradiction, that $\int_a^b \sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\,dx=0$, $f$ and $g$ are both non-negative on $[a,b]$, and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, but $f$ is *not* identically $0$. Then for some $x_0\in[a,b]$, we have $f(x_0)\neq 0$. Since $f$ is non-negative, this reduces to $f(x_0)>0$.

Clearly either $x_0\in(a,b)$, $x_0=a$, or $x_0=b$. If $x_0\in(a,b)$, then the continuity of $f$ implies that for every $\varepsilon >0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for every $x\in[a,b]$, $x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. In particular, this is true for $f(x_0)$, since $f(x_0)>0$. Thus, for some $\delta>0$,

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<f(x_0)\text{ for every }x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$$
$$\iff 0<f(x)<2f(x_0)\text{ for every }x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$$

This shows that $f$ is strictly positive on $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$. Since $g$ is non-negative, we have that $g(x)\geq 0$ on $[a,b]$, so

$$f(x)+g(x)\geq f(x)>0\text{ for every }x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$$
$$\implies\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\geq\sqrt{f(x)}>0\text{ for every }x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$$
$$\implies\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx>0$$

Noting that $\int_{a}^{x_0-\delta}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx\geq 0$ and $\int_{x_0+\delta}^{b}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx\geq 0$, we deduce that their sum is at least zero. This gives the contradiction

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{0} &= \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx\\
&= \int_{a}^{x_0-\delta}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx+\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx+\int_{x_0+\delta}^{b}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx\\
&\color{red}{>} \int_{a}^{x_0-\delta}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx+\int_{x_0+\delta}^{b}\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)}\text{ }dx\\
&\geq \color{green}{0}
\end{align*}

If $x_0=a$ or $x_0=b$, a similar argument applies, the only difference being that we use $[x_0,x_0+\delta]$ and $[x_0-\delta,x_0]$ for $x_0=a$ and $x_0=b$, respectively. We conclude that the stated assumptions necessitate $f$ being identically $0$ on $[a,b]$. $\blacksquare$

I greatly appreciate any and all feedback.

Comment: In general, of $\phi\geq0$ and $\int_I\phi=0$, then $\phi=0$ almost surely in $I$. If $\phi$ is continuous and $I$ is an interval, the proof is easier for if $\phi(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0\in I$, then $\phi(x)>0$ in a small ball $B$ around $x_0$. In fact you can take the small ball so that $\phi(x)>\frac{\phi(x_0)}{2}$. But then $0<\int_{B\cap I}\phi\leq\int_I\phi=0$, a contradiction. Hence $\phi\equiv0$ in $I$. A simple modification will work for your specific problem.

Comment: A few counterexamples, or at least “mini” ones: if a=b then the integral is zero. Also what would be an example of the function $\sqrt {g(x)}$ in an integral being zero with g(x) not being 0 and  non-negative? If f(x)=0 and  g(x)=|x|, then the integral would be $\sqrt{|x|}$ which is never be zero given that $a\ne b$.Maybe complex integration bounds and functions satisfy your conditions also may be a counterexample? I may also be wrong. Please tell me!

Comment: @TymaGaidash I think it's natural to assume that $a\neq b$. Also, any counterexample one conceives of should satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem. As you pointed out, $\int_a^b \sqrt{|x|}dx\neq 0$ for any non-degenerate interval, but this doesn't satisfy the assumption that the integral should be $0$. Also, $\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\sqrt{f(x)}\text{ }dx>0$, so I'm not sure what you're trying to get at with "$\sqrt{g(x)}$ in an integral being $0$ with $g(x)$ nonzero and non-negative". Could you elaborate on this latter bit?

Comment: @AlannRosas sure, it seems that if f=0, then the $\int_a^b \sqrt{0+g(x)}dx=I$, satisfying your conditions, with the I being a constant. This constant _may not be zero_ which does not fit the description in your question above, but this is assuming a condition for the “then” part and then seeing the result in the “if” part. This is like the converse of your “if then title” and not the original. I guess I made a mistake somewhere with this logic.

Comment: @TymaGaidash don't worry about mistakes! It's a normal part of being human. I know for sure I made a _lot_ of them while approaching this problem, and I still don't know if I've addressed them all, hence the post :)

Comment: I think it would also be a good idea to not only expand your toolbox, but also make use of the toolbox you already have. If you know the theorem @OliverDiaz provided, then it would maybe be a good exercise to proof your theorem using that.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use $\varepsilon=f(x_0)/2$ rather than $\varepsilon= f(x_0).$

Then you can say that for $x\in\text{domain}\cap(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta),$ you have $f(x)> f(x_0)/2,$ so $\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)} > \sqrt{f(x_0)/2\,}>0.$ And then you can say the integral is at least $\sqrt{f(x_0)/2\,}\cdot 2\delta>0.$